# How to label vector in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to know how to give a label at the end of a vector in gnuplot. I know it is possible to use "set" in gnuplot to show a certain label at some place, but I have hundreds of vectors to draw, and I want to show the index of each vector at its end, e.g., "Node n". Thus I wonder if it is possible to show the labels with incremental index in "one step" with corresponding vectors.

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04 32bit version. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Use the `with vectors` plotting style for the vectors, and the `with labels` style for the according labels (the zeroth column gives you the row number/vector number). For more details, please show a few lines of your data file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a file with the following data (which I named "temp"), where the first two coordinates are the origin and the last two coordinates are the x and y components (projections) of your vector:

```
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 2
0 0 1 3
0 0 1 4
0 0 1 5
```

Then you can do what you want with the following commands:

```
set xrange [0:1.2]
set yrange [0:6]
plot "temp" with vectors, "temp" u 3:4:0 with labels left
```

The first instance in `plot` is to plot the vectors with the same convention I mentioned above in the data file, the second instance is to place a label with coordinates x = column 3 and y = column 4 (that is, at the end of your vectors), with text = column 0 (which gives the order of your data entries) and flush it to the left from those coordinates. It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! In the beginning, I misunderstood that the last two columns of the data file actually indicate the end point of the vector, but I finally realize that the last two components refer to the delta regarding the start point of the vector, thus in fact, I need to use ($1):($2):($3-$1):($4-$2) to draw the vectors, then it works perfectly.

Comment: @mikegao88 You're right, I changed the text to avoid confusion.