# how to draw horizontal and vertical arrow on histogram

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

```
set title font ", 25" 
set xlabel "FEATURE LENGTH"
set xlabel font ",25"
set ylabel "ACCURACY(%)"
set yrange [45:80]
set ylabel font ",25"
set ytics font ", 25" 
set boxwidth 0.98
set key spacing 3
set key font ",25"
set style fill pattern 10 border lt -1
set style histogram errorbars gap 1 lw 0 
set bars fullwidth

set label 1 '200' front at screen 0.15,.81 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"#(3,6)
set label 2 '200' front at screen 0.18,.82 rotate by 90 font "Arial,17"
set label 3 '300' front at screen 0.24,.80 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18" # {set label 2 'text' front at screen (x,y)0.24,.91 rotate by 90(degree) font "Arial,18"}
set label 4 '1000' front at screen 0.28,.78 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 5 '2000' front at screen 0.33,.66 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 6 '1600' front at screen 0.36,.62 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 7 '1100' front at screen 0.42,.63 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 8 '700' front at screen 0.45,.62 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 9 '500' front at screen 0.51,.59 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 10 '500' front at screen 0.54,.64 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 11 '200' front at screen 0.60,.53 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 12 '25' front at screen 0.69,.41 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 13 '9' front at screen 0.77,.12 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"
set label 14 '383' front at screen 0.86,.60 rotate by 90 font "Arial,18"

set arrow to 1,2

set key inside top center horizontal font "Helvetica, 25" width 1.8
set style histogram clustered #gap 5 title  offset character 0, 0, 0
set xtics font ", 25" 
set xtics ("c1" 0, "c2" 1, "c3" 2, "c4" 3, "c5" 4, "F2" 5, "F3" 6, "F4" 7, "F5" 8)
set style data histograms
#plot "best_feature_neg.dat" using 1 t "{Features without Threshold}",using 2 t "{Features with Threshold}"
plot "best_feature_neg.dat" using 1 t "{/Symbol a}", "" using 2 t "{/Symbol b}"
set output 'best_feature_neg.eps'
set terminal postscript eps enhanced black
replot
```

i want to add a horizontal arrow on first 3 bars and add a label on this arrow.Also i want to put a vertical arrow on first histogram. if anybody know the solution please help me??

My data file is as follows:

> ```
> > 73.6    73.9
> > 73.3    72.5
> > 67.7    66
> > 66.3    66
> > 64.8    66.7
> > 62.5    0
> > 57.3    0
> > 45.8    0
> > 64.8    0
> ```

Comment: For the arrows using values from the data file, use the `vectors` plotting style. For single arrows, use `set arrow`.

Comment: can you explain in detail..

Comment: what is vectors plotting style??..

Comment: is it possible with gnuplot?

Comment: Of course this is possible with gnuplot, otherwise I hadn't written this... Please see e.g. [How to label vector in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088043/how-to-label-vector-in-gnuplot) (Second hit on http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[gnuplot]+vectors) or the documentation for the vectors plotting style for trying it yourself ;)

Comment: sorry..i need an arrow on my histrogram from 1 bar to 3 bar..the link you provided didnt give enough information for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an arrow from the first bar `c1` to the third one `c3`, you can use the command

```
set arrow from first 0,graph 0.95 to first 2, graph 0.95 filled linewidth 2
```

For an explanation of the different coordinate systems `first` and `graph`, please see [place label aligned to right, at certain y coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23180595/2604213) or type `help coordinates` in the interactive gnuplot terminal.

If I include this arrow command in your script, I get (with 4.6.5):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much..for vertical arrow                                                               "set arrow from first 0,graph 0.9 to first 0,graph 0.99 filled linewidth 5 linecolor rgb "red"