# Custom Labeling Scheme of Vectors in Gnuplot

Tags: vector, label, gnuplot

I used the information provided in

[How to label vector in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088043/how-to-label-vector-in-gnuplot)

to label some of my plotted vectors. The issue is that I have twenty vectors, but I don't want twenty different labels. Every two vectors have the same label. E.g. the 0th and the 1st have label "1", the 2nd and 3rd have label "2", et cetera. How can I create a custom labeling scheme to do this without labeling each vector manually? Doing this manually is not practical because I have several files and twenty vectors to label for each file.

This is my command:

```
plot "gnuCors.txt" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors, "gnuCors.txt" u 5:6:0 with labels left
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your vectors get labeled with the value `int($0)/2 + 1`:

```
plot "gnuCors.txt" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors,\
     "" u 5:6:(int($0)/2 + 1) with labels left offset 0.5
```

Note, that this should work fine, but sometimes gnuplot has troubles to automatically convert the number given in the last using column. Then you should explicitely format the values with `sprintf`:

```
plot "gnuCors.txt" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors,\
     "" u 5:6:(sprintf("%d", int($0)/2 + 1)) with labels left offset 0.5
```